# Django | Error al hacer una insert: Cannot assign "1": "UserAnswers.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-models

Al tratar de hacer una nueva insert, me devuelve el siguiente error: Cannot assign "1": "UserAnswers.user" must be a "User" instance. ¿Qué sucede? Los que me **dan problema son User y Modality**, precisamente los que tienen ForeignKey. Ya que si los quito, no hay ningún error, claro que necesito insertar esos datos también.
Gracias.

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Views.py**

```
...

user = 1
modality = 1
numberQuestion = 1
correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion = 1
correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion = 0

newAnswer = UserAnswers.objects.create(user=userId, modality=modalityPost, numberQuestion=numberQuestion, correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=correctCounterNewInsert, wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=wrongCounterNewInsert)
newAnswer.save()
...
```

**Models.py:**

```
class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    numberQuestion = models.IntegerField('Número pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta correctamente',null=True,blank=True)
    wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta incorrectamente',null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: Debes asignarle un objeto usuario, no el id.

Comment: Así funciona bien: user_id=userId, modality_id=modalityPost ¡Gracias Sergio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiendo _id funciona perfecto. Había probado __id pero me devuelve error. En cambio _id funciona bien.

```
newAnswer = UserAnswers.objects.create(user_id=userId, modality_id=modalityPost, numberQuestion=numberQuestion, correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=correctCounterNewInsert, wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=wrongCounterNewInsert)
newAnswer.save()
```

Un saludo.